# Logic for finding all possible words that can be spelled with a phone number on a dial pad

Tags: java, search, combinations

So I have to find all possible combinations that can be spelled with a phone number using the letters assigned for each number on a dial pad. ie: 222 6262 can spell "A BANANA".

Given any number of any length < 8, I can find a all the words that match the whole number. Ie, `findWholeWord(dictionary[2], 723)` will give me an array of strings `{"RAD", "RAE", "RAF", "SAD", "SBF", "PAE", "PAD"}` (the dictionary I was given is sort of dumb...). My dictionary is split into 7 parts with each part containing words of the same length.

What I am not sure is how to take a 7 digit number and give all word combinations, like one word length 6, one word lenght 1 (6, 1), 5 and 2, 5 and 1 and 1, 4 and 3, 4 and 2 and 1. I want to throw out anything that doesn't cover the whole word (anything with 0 or 1, a 3 letter and 2 letter word that has no match for the last 2 letters). I don't know how to go about this logic. I'm pretty sure this sort of logic has a name because I drew out a tree and it has a nice pattern, but I don't know what that pattern is called or what exactly it is called.

One way is to find all sub-words and try to fit them together in any way that works, the other is to try all possible combinations of word lengths: (7), (6,1), (5,2), (5,1,1), (4,3), (4,2,1), (4,1,2), (4,1,1,1) and so on...

Not sure how to do either, not sure which would be easier, not sure which one would be most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution, but it depends on if these dictionaries are updated at runtime, or fixed at developing time. If these dictionaries don't change by time, you might do the following:

1. Perform a pre-processing task on the dictionaries you have, so that for every word in every dictionary, you create the equivalent number (i.e. for "BANANA" give "226262") in some simple data structure.
2. Store these dictionaries in a database of 7 tables (a table per word length) indexed by the "Word" field, so that you can read them again at runtime in your program.
3. Create a Method that takes a given number "2226262" and returns a String ArrayList. For N = 1 to 7 ; takes the 1st N digits and searches for the possible words in the "N Table" using the digits you have. For every possible word you got, call the same method again with the rest of the digits for every word (i.e. if a Word is 3 characters, then call the method with the last 4 digits). Create a new String ArrayList and add all results obtained from these calls subsequently, and return it.
4. Make sure to make the terminating condition for this recursion to avoid "Infinite Recursion". I suggest to check at the beginning of the method if the given number is Zero length, and if so, simply return an empty String ArrayList.

I hope that I made my point clear

**UPDATE**

Here's a sudo code of what I'm saying:

```
ArrayList<String> getWordsOf(String Number){
    if(Number.isEmpty()){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    ArrayList<String> allPossibleWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=Number.length(); i++){
        ArrayList<String> possibleWords = getFromDataBase(Number.substring(0,i));
        ArrayList<String> restOfPossibleWords = getWordsOf(Number.substring(i,Number.length()-i));
        for(String possibleWord:possibleWords){
            for(String restOfPossibleWord:restOfPossibleWords){
                allPossibleWords.add(possibleWord+" "+restOfPossibleWord);
            }
        }
    }
    return allPossibleWords;
}
```

Comment: I've got 1 and 2 down (what I actually did was I sorted the dictionary based on numerical value using Arrays.sort and a custom comparator; then I do the individual searching by converting dictionary to those numbers (which is now in ascending order) and do a binary search using Arrays.binarySearch). However, it is 3 and 4 that I am not sure about. I have a vague idea at what you are getting at, but I am not sure about the details.

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure I understand the logic, especially the lines defining possibleWords and restOfPossibleWords. Unfortunately, I am completely unfamiliar with ArrayLists. Would this require much modification to just use arrays?

Comment: I can't think of an easy switch for the same logic to use Arrays instead of ArrayLists. It's very easy to use ArrayLists ! You create them as in: "ArrayList<String> allPossibleWords = new ArrayList<String>();" and add items to it as "allPossibleWords.add(item);" and you pass through it's items using the enhanced for as above, and finally if you want to get the element "i" you just write "allPossibleWords.get(i)". It's really simple. For more, you can see: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying all the possible combination, it might save you time, if you kept a count on the number of words you have got for each index...
for eg. in `findWholeWord(dictionary[2], 723); wordCount[2]=7;`
So lets for the sake of clarity you get `wordCount[0]=1; wordCount[5]=3;` (I can't imagine you getting any other 1 letter word but 'A'), this would mean that you now have to run just 1X3 combinations instead of 7X7. Would save your sub-word matching some significant time.